# the precise meaning of get you up

Tags: vocabulary

I read a sentence:

> This quick start **gets you up** to speed quickly with regular expressions.
>   [Regular Expressions Quick Start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

which briefly means that

> This quick start **helps** you to speed quickly with regular expressions.

Nevertheless, the precise meaning of 'get up' is obscure for me to understand.

It's a metaphor?
Given a scene,I fell asleep without any knowledge of regular expression, then the quick start wakes me up quicker than normal speed?

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+to+speed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom is "to get up to speed", and can't be broken into parts:

> **[up to speed](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+to+speed)** : 1 operating at full speed. 2 (of a person or company) performing at an anticipated rate or level. 3 (of a person) fully informed or up to date.

example:

> I've been tasked with updating the company website, but it'll take me a while to **get up to speed** on the latest JavaScript frameworks.

The metaphor is like a car accelerating on to a highway, where you try to *get up to speed* (as quickly as possible) in order to merge with traffic.  Alternately, like a train working to *get up to speed* in order to move its freight most efficiently.